# Android virtual device shows only android text and not start

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have created  a virtual device using android virtual device manager.

[image]

Then I started it:

[image]

But by now i'm waiting for 50 minutes nothing happens and the only thing visible is the android logo . it is using 50% of my cpu and my os hangs slowly but nothing happens. what is wrong?

Comment: I would recommend build on physical device instead virtual device.

Comment: I'm new to android. i think it is hard and time-wasting to build in physical device.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Most android programmers that I know use physical devices. Please read: [Rely only on Real – Emulators vs. Devices](http://testdroid.com/news/rely-only-on-real-emulators-vs-devices)

Comment: Default virtual device is very slow. You can use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). It's better.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled Intel Hyper-v in your BIOS?.

Comment: @Hoang Nguyen default? I will check genymotion . thank you for your comment

Comment: @Smashing no i have not. Shall I do it from control panel or bios?

Comment: From the BIOS of your PC. If you are using Windows. Just search around for Inter Hyper-V or Intel Virtualization.

Comment: Oh and +1 for Genymotion, although the Android Studio 2.0 VM looks a lot better.

Comment: And again useless down voters are on work!

Answer (score 0):

Increased the **Device RAM Size to 1024** which results in a fast emulator.

**check snapshot feature** (lastone in screenshot you gave) in emulation options it will speedup your process

Read this document for more detail http://jolicode.com/blog/speed-up-your-android-emulator

Comment: Thank yoy- i will check - would you please upvote my question so i can upvote your answer

Comment: Please inform if having problem.@Dexter

Comment: have you checked this?@Dexter